# Getting incorrect result when using IS NOT NULL with COUNT function - MySQL

Tags: mysql, count, null

I have a table of music tracks with a length field that stores information on how long each individual track is. I'm trying to query to database to find out the maximum track length, minimum track length and I want the return the number of tracks which have a length listed (IS NOT NULL).

Here is the statement:

```
SELECT MAX(length), MIN(length), COUNT(length)
FROM tracks WHERE length IS NOT NULL;
```

The problem is the value COUNT() returns is the exact same whether I include the IS NOT NULL operator at the end or not. The table has around 25 entries that are NULL so surely I should be getting a lower result for COUNT() when I add the NOT NULL operator to the end of the statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation says that count will ignore null columns
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/counting-rows.html

Including the where clause will not make a difference.

Comment: This is correct.  If you want to count *all rows matched by `WHERE`*, use `COUNT(*)` or `COUNT(1)` (they are equivalent).  If you want to count rows where col1 is not null, that's exactly what `COUNT(col1)` does.

Answer (score 0):

**BACKTICKS** are your friend: **length** is a function name in MySQL and if you want o use it as field name you must put it in backticks like this:

```
SELECT MAX(`length`), MIN(`length`), COUNT(`length`)
FROM tracks WHERE `length` IS NOT NULL;
```